# Displaying function values onto an already existing EJS template

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I need to display a value from a JS file (`indexRoutes.js`) into an input box on an EJS template (`calculator.ejs`), I have included the script via a footer I have made.

This is the code for the JS Function I have:

```
router.post("/calculator", (req, res) => {
  let ethAddress = req.body.ethereumAddress;
/*BEGINNING OF CALCULATION METHOD
  /* PART 1 For getting data, using node-fetch .json to convert the data into an array of objects*/
  function APIRetrieval() {
    var userTransactions = [];
    var totalValue = 0;
    fetch(
      `https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=txlist&address=${ethAddress}&startblock=0&endblock=99999999&sort=asc&apikey=${APIKey}`
    )
      .then((data) => {
        return data.json();
      })
      .then((retrievedData) => {
        // Extract just the results from the Javascript object for a Javascript object of just the transactions.
        userTransactions = retrievedData.result;

        // This loop takes all values from all previous transactions and adds them together for a number to be used in the calculation of emissions.
        for (var i = 0; i < userTransactions.length; i++) {
          // console.log(userTransactions[i].gasPrice);
          let currentValue = Number(userTransactions[i].gasPrice);
          totalValue = totalValue + currentValue;
        }
      });
  }
  APIRetrieval();
});
```

This is the code for the EJS Form that I have:

```html
<form action="/calculator" method="POST">
  <div class="form-group px-5 mt-4">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
      <label for="ethAddress">Ethereum Address</label>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center mt-2">
      <input
        type="string"
        id="ethereumAddress"
        name="ethereumAddress"
        class="form-control"
        placeholder="Enter Ethereum Address"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-4">Calculate</button>
  </div>
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-center mt-4">
    <label for="emissionValue">Total Emission Price To Offset</label>
  </div>
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-center mt-2 mb-4">
    <input
      type="string"
      id="emissionValue"
      name="emissionValue"
      class="form-control"
      placeholder=""
      value=""
      readonly
    />
  </div>
</form>
```

I want to display the `totalValue` value from the JS file, inside the `emissionValue` input after the post request has been submitted, the post request is fully functioning and does work, I just do not know how to replace the empty value inside `emissionValue` whilst using NodeJS and Express.

I understand it does not come with a DOM, however, I have no idea how to tackle this. I have also tried to look into `JSDom` but I cannot understand this exact scenario.

This is my File Structure:
[File Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAZQQ.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing your `ejs` file is named `calculator.ejs` and that you added already in your main file the `ejs` middleware and `ejs` setup.

In your endpoint, when you send the response, you can send it like this:

```
router.post("/calculator", (req, res) => {
  let ethAddress = req.body.ethereumAddress;
/*BEGINNING OF CALCULATION METHOD
  /* PART 1 For getting data, using node-fetch .json to convert the data into an array of objects*/
  function APIRetrieval() {
    var userTransactions = [];
    var totalValue = 0;
    fetch(
      `https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=txlist&address=${ethAddress}&startblock=0&endblock=99999999&sort=asc&apikey=${APIKey}`
    )
      .then((data) => {
        return data.json();
      })
      .then((retrievedData) => {
        // Extract just the results from the Javascript object for a Javascript object of just the transactions.
        userTransactions = retrievedData.result;

        // This loop takes all values from all previous transactions and adds them together for a number to be used in the calculation of emissions.
        for (var i = 0; i < userTransactions.length; i++) {
          // console.log(userTransactions[i].gasPrice);
          let currentValue = Number(userTransactions[i].gasPrice);
          totalValue = totalValue + currentValue;
        }
      });
      return totalValue;
  }
  const totalValue = APIRetrieval();
  res.render("calculator.ejs", {totalValue: totalValue});
});
```

You bassically render that file and send values to it, values that you can use inside it
In your `calculator.ejs` you can use now:

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center mt-2 mb-4">
          <input
            type="string"
            id="emissionValue"
            name="emissionValue"
            class="form-control"
            placeholder=""
            value="<%= totalValue =>"
            readonly
          />
        </div>
```

Comment: I get the error totalValue is not defined. Is this because I am out of scope or is there another issue? I will add my file structure to the post to see if this helps.

Comment: You're right, I haven't noticed that. Please see the updated code. You have to get that value outside of APIRetrieval function's scope and send it to your `ejs` file

Comment: It still says that it is not defined, the value should only be set after the post has happened, is there a way I set a value before the post so that the page loads? or is there an alternative?